# How to sum entries that have same ID OpenOffice - Calc

Tags: openoffice-calc

I have a spreadsheet similar to the one in the screenshot.
[image: Current Data]

From this I want to sum all the entries in Data 2 which have the same Data 1 ID and store it in another column. So something like this:

[image: The end result]

I am not able to figure out the formula which would do this. I figured out how to get a column with unique entries I just need to figure out how to get the sum of the values which have the same data 1 id.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `SUMIF`, e.g. if I'm reading your sheet right, `=SUMIF(A$2:A$7, A11, B$2:B$7)`, and then copy down.  This sums the values from B2-B7 whenever the corresponding value in A2-A7 matches A11.

You can find more on `SUMIF` [here](http://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Calc:_SUMIF_function).

[image: sumif example]

Comment: What if I want to do something similar with string values?
Let's assume the ID's to be the same 111.
Assume the values in B column to be ('This', 'is', 'test') instead of (101, 9879, 328)

So instead, of concatenating the string, it should put the values in `column C` and `column D`

Answer (score 0):

you may use subtotals function under the Data tab, although it gives you the answer in the row below all the cell matching your id; then you have to click the - and + buttons that appear on the left...[you may see these in this picture of my data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uWQX5.png)
this is a nice resource when you have non-English characters(á, ó, ß,...), spaces, dashes and points, so it becomes difficult to process with sql